# Update metadata of an Amazon S3 object with non-English values

Tags: php, amazon-s3, metadata

I have been using Amazon AWS SDK2 for PHP to interact to Amazon S3 service.

Is it possible to **save metadata** value (x-amz-meta-*) in **non-English characters**.

I have even tried directly adding a new metadata inside S3 console.

Can anybody let me know if it is possible at all and is there way to save metadata for an object in non English text.

Thank you in advance,

Ankit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found that it is not possible to save non-english text as metadata value for an object in Amazon s3.

Below is a snippet from documentation :

> A value pair must conform to US-ASCII when using REST and UTF-8 when
>   using SOAP

If anyone has any other idea on this, please share.

Thanks.